# Does a Threshold reduces magic Power or Control?

Tags: fate, dresden-files

When crossing a Threshold uninvited, what does a Wizard has to deal with?

Does the Threshold strength reduces Spells **Power** (Shifts of power limited by *Conviction*), **Control** (*Discipline* test to handle/target the spell) or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Story page 230:

> **How It Works**
>   A threshold can operate in four different modes: as a
>   block, a target, a suppressor, or a source of harm.

In the context of this question, target and harm aren't relevant, but block and suppressor are.

As a block, the Threshold sets a minimum difficulty. As a suppressor, affected spells and abilities lose a number of shifts equal to the strength of the threshold.

*"Does the Threshold strength reduces Spells Power (Shifts of power limited by Conviction), Control (Discipline test to handle/target the spell) or both?"*

Well, one or the other, depending on whether it's a block (Control/Discipline) or a suppressor (Power/Conviction).

It's up to the GM to determine which of the two options are more appropriate based on the fictional positioning.